# Android app port to iOS without paying $99 fee?

Tags: android, ios, iphone

I made a simple [android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tapdat) as a side project. I currently am not interested in monetizing the app in any serious manner (but may in the future via ads, which I already added) and this project is mainly just for fun. That being said, I wanted to port it to iOS so that I don't miss out on the user base but didn't feel as though the $99/year was worth it for a project that I'm not very interested in monetizing. Do I have any viable options? Could I recreate the entire app in html/JS and direct users to a QR code that would dynamically redirect them to the in-store Google Play app if they're on android or to a web-based version if they're on iOS, which would basically be a website built for serving iOS devices?

I know that most web-based apps are made and then hosted inside of a webview that is native to the device but is it possible to circumnavigate this (and therefore circumnavigate the problem of having to publish with apple) and host the app as a website to which I direct people?

Edit: Open to any suggestions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porting it to a web based app would have its limitation, mainly on the connectivity and hardware access for the iOS device. It could be troublesome for non android users.

My advice is that you should get a developer account, as it is a great investment. If getting a mac is expensive, try a Hackintosh.

When your app takes off, you will easily get your $99 back in a year from ads.

Comment: I'm thinking about attempting to make a web-based version. From the brief reading that I've done so far it seems as though most hardware capabilities have been worked out that I need (mainly GPS and internal storage). If it ends up working well, I could make a webview-based app for iOS that simply pulls up the page but it seems like it's already possible to create a link to the page on iOS (from inside the app).

Comment: There is an option on the Iphone/ipads where the user could create shortcuts or the website on the phone/pad itself and it resembles an icon of an actual application. I've have tried this for demo project. It help in getting the ball moving in terms of functional testing as well as User interface evaluation.

I've also test HTML5 which offers a semi-workable offline viewing function. IT basically means that you could create webapps that work even if the phone has not internet connection.

However I hope you would consider a native app for the final goal.

Answer (score 2):

The $99 fee is in order to become an Apple App Store developer.  You can download Xcode for free and tinker around with an app, but if you want an app on the Apple App Store, whether for free or monetized, there is no way around paying the $99 fee (other than paying the $199 or $299 enterprise fee, I'm not certain the actual price on this one).

**TL;DR If you want an app on Apple's App Store, you must pay the $99 fee.  Period.**

Comment: So what about my idea of hosting a website specifically for iOS users and directing people to it? Obviously the only downside is them not having access to an easy to click icon on their device to pull up the app but I'm sure I could find a way around this to the end of an alternative means of easy access.

Comment: Of course, if you host a website, I can browse to it in Safari on my iOS device (or Android device, or desktop computer, or gaming console, or smart TV, or whatever), but as far as I'm consider, this isn't actually "porting" your app to iOS.  This is porting your app to the web.

Comment: Are you aware of a reason why this would not be viable in my case? Do web-based apps have limited access to any key pieces of functionality that only native apps can achieve?

Comment: Web-based apps can't do everything a native app can do.  I don't know whether or not your app will need to do anything that can't be done by a web app, because I don't know any of the details of your app.  You can easily figure out whether or not you'd be able to do it all from the web by simply writing the web app and seeing if you can do it all... whether you browse to it from a desktop or Android device or iOS device, it should behave mostly the same...